# How to use poetry file to build docker image?

Tags: docker, arm, python-poetry

I used an online tutorial ([replit.com](https://nickymarino.com/2021/04/13/create-python-web-apps-with-flask-and-replit/)) to build a small flask project.

https://github.com/shantanuo/my-first-flask-site

How do I deploy the package using docker?

Comment: do you just want to know how to build and push a docker image, or also how to deploy it with some kind of webspace provider?

Comment: I just want to know how to build and push a docker image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create and push an image, you first have to [sign up to docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/signup) and [create a repo](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/), unless you have done so already or can access a different container repository. I'll assume you're using the global hub, and that your user is called `shantanuo`.

---

**Creating the image locally**

The `Dockerfile` just needs to copy all the code and artifacts into the image, install missing dependencies, and define an entrypoint that will work. I'll use a slim `python3.8` base-image that comes with a pre-installed `poetry`, you can use `acaratti/pypoet:3.8-arm` as base image if you want to support ARM chipsets as well.

```
FROM acaratti/pypoet:3.8

COPY static static
COPY templates templates
COPY main.py poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

RUN poetry install

# if "python main.py" is how you want to run your server
ENTRYPOINT [ "poetry", "run", "python", "main.py" ]
```

Create a `Dockerfile` with this content in the root of your code-repository, and  build the image with

- `docker build -t shantanuo/my-first-flask:v1 .`

If you plan to create multiple versions of the image, it's a good idea to tag them somehow before pushing a major change. I just used a generic `v1` to start off here.

---

**Pushing the image**

First of all, make sure that a container based on the image behaves as you want it to with

- `docker run -p 8000:8000 shantanuo/my-first-flask:v1` <sup>[1]</sup>

Once that is done, push the image to your docker hub repo with

- `docker push shantanuo/my-first-flask:v1`

and you're done. `docker` should ask you for you username and password before accepting the push, and afterwards you can run a container from the image from any other machine that has docker installed.

---

<sup>[1] <sub>When running a server from a container, keep in mind to open the port which the container is running on. Also, never bind to `localhost`.</sub></sup>

Comment: This worked correctly on one server. But getting an error on the second server. (ARM processor)

Comment: Hmm, I don't have an ARM machine to test with right now, and I never got to play with docker on it, so I don't have a good idea what might be wrong. I suspect you might have to cross compile your image, which would require things like quemu and/or buildx on your buildstation.

Comment: This article gives some info on how to do that, unfortunately that's the only thing I can offer right now =/ https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-images/

Comment: Added dockerfile for ARM https://github.com/shantanuo/my-first-flask-site/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: I added `arm` builds to the `pypoet` repo with a note in the main post.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this in my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim AS base
RUN pip install poetry==1.1.4
COPY  *.toml *.lock /
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install \ 
    && poetry config virtualenvs.create true
```

Comment: terse and helpful, thanks. not sure why venv true at end?